# Handle empty body response from service

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlinx.coroutines

Im trying to call a service via POST that sends an e-mail to the user, the body always return empty, I have to deal with the response code. 
e.g. 204 = success.

Im trying to deal this way, but im not succeeding

Service:

```
@POST("xxxxxx")
fun resendBankSlip(@Path("userId") userId: Int): Deferred<Response>
```

ViewModel:

```
scope.launch {
        try {
            _loading.value = true
            val response = repository.sendEmail(userId)
            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                _error.value = R.string.generic_error_message
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            _error.value = R.string.generic_error_message
        } finally {
            _loading.value = false
        }
    }
```

The error happens on `val response = repository.sendEmail(userId)`

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'okhttp3.Response' is not a valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?
for method EmailService.sendEmail
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably confused `okhttp3.Response` with `retrofit.Response`. Try to use `retrofit2.Response` wrapper in API response like that:

```
@POST("xxxxxx")
fun resendBankSlip(@Path("userId") userId: Int): Deferred<retrofit2.Response<Unit>>
```

After that you can easily get response code via `response.code()`.

Also note that I passed `Unit` as `Response`'s type argument because you don't need the body. In other cases you should pass an actual type of response body.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: @sma6871 you're right, use Unit in Kotlin and Void in Java